# Why the SDL Tridion Sites 9.1 Content Service with Context Cartridge "Cannot Find Repository"?

Tags: sites-9.1, context-engine, content-service, add-on

We are running the SDL Tridion Sites 9.1 Content Service and we have the context extension installed using the add-on service (udp-context-extension-assembly-XYZ-core).

We are running the content service on Linux.  When the service boots, the context-extension is pulled down and unzipped successfully.  It appears that the extension is loaded when the content service boots as well, so no issue there.  However in our cd_core log we can see the following ERROR:

```
2020-07-30 20:17:53,601 ERROR [main] LazyRepositoryLocation - Cannot find repository at ../repository : File ../repository does not exist at path /aFolder/sdl-services/develop/sessioncontent/extensions/context-extension/../repository
```

Which resolves to: "/aFolder/sdl-services/develop/sessioncontent/extensions/repository".  However, as per the documentation (step 7: https://docs.sdl.com/783502/676330/sdl-tridion-sites-9-1/creating-the-device-database), we have placed the repository under "/aFolder/sdl-services/develop/sessioncontent/services/repository".  I know that the extensions folder is cleaned during every service boot, so we can't add it directly in there.  Have we missed a step in adding the repository or is there perhaps a configuration location where we can set the repository path to the "/services" folder instead?

Comment: please raise to SDL support